# Restore overwritten PATH variable

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

I installed a program that cleared my %PATH% (probably [this NSIS bug](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Path_Manipulation#Warning)).
I don't want to run System Restore because of other changes I made that I suspect will be reverted (for example, my backup configuration).

Is there a way to recover the PATH from a system restore point or any other good way?

Comment: Pull it out of your mentioned backup?

Comment: @techie007 Unfortunately, one of the reasons I had to reconfigure the backup was because it was not backing up the registry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet00х\Control\Session Manager\Environment
Path
```

command line, LastKnownGood:

```
REG Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\Select" /v LastKnownGood
```

get all ControlSet00х hive list:

```
REG Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\Select"
```

get Path at ControlSet002:

```
REG Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path
```

Comment: Perfect, it was in ControlSet002. I need to learn more about how Last Known Good Configuration works.

Comment: @yakatz http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2011/08/05/last-known-good.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, which I did just now, is to download a program called [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) and examine the environment of a program that was running before whatever overwrote your PATH. Of course, that only works if you're still running a program that was open before your PATH got overwritten, but I was, so I was able to salvage it.